# Align Object With Triangle

Tags: directx

I currently am trying to figure out how rotate an object so it's aligned with a triangle along the Z Axis. I have the world matrix of the object and a triangle, which has it's 3 points and the normal. My goal is to try and get the y axis of the object to face the same as the triangle's face normal.

Currently, what I have works on normals that are facing the positive y, however if it's facing downward (<0) the the object will rotate the until it's is facing the opposite direction as the triangle's normal.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
compWorld.GetYAxis( axis );
result = axis.Cross( triColWith->vNormal );
compWorld.Rotate( D3DXToDegree( result.x ), 0, D3DXToDegree( result.z ) );
```

I would like to thank you in advance for any help you could provide me. If anything needs more explanation, feel free to ask.

Comment: Why not just make your normal negative?